# VBA Range.value function causing unexpected end

Tags: vba, excel

This must seem like a terribly simple question, but I cannot figure out why my functions are ending unexpectedly on the Range.value = val call. Perhaps I am missing something very basic, but I have tested these out and each one of them are failing to resolve to anything and I don't know how to capture the error.

Here is the initial function:

```
Function incrementCount(upper As Range, Summed As Range, ParamArray sums() As Variant)

Dim deduct As Integer
Dim summation As Integer
Dim elem As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim temp As Range
up = upper.Value
summation = Summed.Value
'Initialize the starting points of the increments
For i = LBound(sums) To UBound(sums)
    MsgBox IsObject(sums(i)) 'Prints out as an true
    MsgBox TypeName(sums(i)) 'Prints out as Rnage
    MsgBox sums(i).Value 'Prints out as 0
    Set temp = sums(i) 
    MsgBox temp.Value 'Prints out as 0
    Set temp = Summed
    MsgBox temp.Value 'Prints out as 1 (which is correct)
    temp.value = 3 'Errors here
    MsgBox temp.Value 'Never makes it to this line
    sums(i).Value = 1 'I have also tried this with the same result
Next i

<more code that is never reached>

End Function
```

I am at my wits end. I have searched MSDN, stackoverflow, and all the many excel forums and all of them show setting values to a range like this. I have even separated the setting of a range value to a different function like this:

```
Function testsub(thecell As Range, thevalue As Integer)
    thecell.value = thevalue
End Function
```

Ultimately i would like to be able to do something like discussed in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168151/vba-pass-a-group-of-cells-as-range-to-function) where I loop over a random assortment of ranges and will increment them. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without concentrating on the code, can you please tell us exactly what you're trying to do? I think this code is kind of over-complicated for a simple task, based on the post you're referring to.

Comment: I am attempting to find the optimal number of increments for a set values to reach a specified sum. ie, 1st set is x *4 and 2nd is x*6, what does x need to be to equal y (some sum). Is there a built in function that can do this?

Comment: It should also be noted that x*4 and x*6 are not in adjacent cells. I couldn't get goal seek to work becuase it doesn't increment all of them at once.

Comment: First, I second @David Zemens in his comment below that it should be a subroutine. Second, why not use Solver for this? If it's an optimization scenario you need, I suggest using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified how **IncrementCount()** is being called.

If your function is being called from a worksheet cell, then it is "bombing out" at the correct line.  A UDF called from a cell cannot modify the contents of other cells, it can only return a value.

Comment: Ok, that is what i am attempting to do. I wasn't aware of that fact. Is there a way to alter another cells value, perhaps by calling a subroutine within the function?

Comment: Only indirectly...................you could re-architect your system to have the UDF return a value to a cell and have a Calculate event macro respond to the calculation.

Comment: I was able to get this to work by calling it through a subroutine. Thanks for the help!