# VBA function with a variable number of arrays as arguments

Tags: vba

There are quite a few posts on how to create a vba function with a variable number of arguments using ParamArray. But I need to create a function with a variable number of arrays as arguments. That is, my function will have at least two arrays as inputs, but may have several.

The function may appear as:

```
MyFunc(A1:A10,B1:B10)
```

in which case it will have two arrays as parameters, or it may be:

```
MyFunc(A1:A10,B1:B10,C1:C10,D1:D10)
```

in which case there will be four arrays.Can VBA handle this type of function. If so, how?

Comment: To be clear, I'm hoping to write a user defined function that can be used in the worksheet (in a cell). The functionality that I'm after is like the `sumproduct` formula - it can handle up to 255 arrays (or ranges from which the arrays can be extracted).

Comment: After MNS pointed out that I was actually looking for a function with a variable number of _ranges_, not a variable number of _arrays_, I did some more searching and fond the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168151/vba-pass-a-group-of-cells-as-range-to-function). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Following is one method to pass variable number of ranges, as shown in your question.

```
Sub MyFunc(ByRef Ranges() As Range)

    Dim ObjCell As Range
    Dim nIndex As Integer
    For nIndex = 0 To UBound(Ranges)
        For Each ObjCell In Ranges(nIndex).Cells
            MsgBox ObjCell.Text
        Next ObjCell
    Next nIndex
End Sub
```

And call above function as shown below.

```
Public Sub Auto_open()

    Dim Ranges(4) As Range

    Set Ranges(0) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")
    Set Ranges(1) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B10")
    Set Ranges(2) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C10")
    Set Ranges(3) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D10")

    MyFunc Ranges

End Sub
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I'm actually trying to write a function that can be used in the workbook (in a cell). I've added a comment to my original question for clarification. The MyFunc code above breaks down if I convert it to a function (even if I modify the code to make it simply return `UBound(Ranges)`.