# Excel VBA Function to cycle through range and measure multiple correlations

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create an Excel VBA function that cycles through a `cycle_range` and calculates the correlation each range of 5 cell entries within that range to a `base_range` of 5 cell entries.  The function should return the maximum correlation in the cycle_range.  For example, the following data should return the 0.506..... output, as the second set of cycle range numbers, `7, 8, 9, 0, 8`, have that correlation to the base range, which is the highest correlation:

```
cycle range     base range       output
     4              3          0.506253796
     7              7   
     8              3   
     9              2   
     0              9   
     8      
     5      
     4
```

The code I have thus far is below, it doesn't work.  There is very clearly a problem with adding rng and elements together from cycle_range, but not sure what to do:

```
Function best_correl(correl_length As Double, base_range As Range, cycle_range As Range)


Dim i As Double
Dim rng As Range
Dim cycle_range_length As Double
Dim element As Variant
Dim max_correl As Double
Dim curr_correl As Double


cycle_range_length = cycle_range.Count - correl_length


For i = 1 To cycle_range_length

    For element = 1 To correl_length
        rng = rng + element
    Next element

    curr_correl = WorksheetFunction.Correl(base_range, rng)

    If curr_correl > max_correl Then
        max_correl = curr_correl
    End If

Next i


best_correl = max_correl


End Function
```

As always, any advice is very much appreciated, I'm having a tough time with this one.  Thank you!

P.S.  I cribbed some stuff from here - [vba pass a group of cells as range to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168151/vba-pass-a-group-of-cells-as-range-to-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Function best_correl(correl_length As Double, base_range As Range, cycle_range As Range)

    Dim c As Range
    Dim cycle_range_length As Long
    Dim max_correl As Double
    Dim curr_correl As Double, n As Long, pos as Long

    cycle_range_length = 1 + (cycle_range.Count - correl_length)
    n = 0
    pos = 0
    For Each c In cycle_range.Resize(cycle_range_length, 1).Cells
        n = n + 1             
        curr_correl = WorksheetFunction.Correl(base_range, c.Resize(correl_length, 1))
        If curr_correl > max_correl Then  
            max_correl = curr_correl
            pos = n  
        End If
    Next c

    'best_correl = max_correl '<< max correlation
    best_correl = pos         '<< position of max 

End Function
```

Comment: @ Tim Williams one other question - if I wanted to return, instead of the correlation, the location of the max_correl (i.e. if it's the second range in the cycle, then best_correl = 2), is it possible to have the code return that output, instead?

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
Function best_correl(correl_length As Double, base_range As Range, cycle_range As Range)

Dim MyCell As Range
Dim max_correl As Double
Dim curr_correl As Double

For Each MyCell In cycle_range
    curr_correl = Application.WorksheetFunction.Correl(base_range, MyCell)
        If curr_correl > max_correl Then
            max_correl = curr_correl
        End If
Next MyCell

best_correl = max_correl


End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, but this just looks cell by cell, I believe - the correl function has to go over a range.  In my example, there should 4 iterations of the loop, as there are 9 total cells in cycle range - so four ranges of 5 cells.  Might not understand what you're code is doing though.